# Unable to pick Checkbox properly in grid

Tags: visual-foxpro

I've manual pick problem for those checkbox layout in grid's first columns where there are all created in class object.

I'm able to picked success on first row, but it won't be appear when click on second row.

check box in entire column seem to be failed in random picked and unable to pick in identical for each row.

Coding :

```
define class chk_sel as checkbox
name = "chk_sel"

procedure init

this.value = 0
this.caption    = ""
this.readonly   = .f.
this.tabstop    = .f.

endproc

enddefine

Define class frmpurc As Form

procedure init

For frm in _screen.Forms
if frm.name == "MyForm"
select "" as pick,supcode,item_desc,inv_no,po_no,line,acc_qty, ;
taxcode,acc_amt,net_tax,gros_amt from purc ;
into cursor tmpcur ;
where alltrim(inv_no) = alltrim(this.txt_search.value)

If NOT USED('tmpcur_')
USE DBF("tmpcur") in 0 AGAIN alias tmpcur_
else
USE IN 'tmpcur_'
USE DBF("tmpcur") in 0 AGAIN alias tmpcur_
endif

sele tmpcur_

frm.grid_list.recordsource  = SPACE(0)
frm.grid_list.recordsource = "tmpcur_"
frm.grid_list.deletemark    = .f.
frm.grid_list.readonly  = .f.

frm.grid_list.column1.width = 25
frm.grid_list.column1.bound = .f.
frm.grid_list.column1.controlsource = "tmpcur_.pick"
frm.grid_list.column1.readonly  = .f.

frm.grid_list.column1.text1.visible = .t.
frm.grid_list.column1.removeobject("text1")
frm.grid_list.column1.addobject("pick","chk_sel")

frm.grid_list.column1.currentcontrol = "pick"
frm.grid_list.column1.pick.visible = .t.
frm.grid_list.column1.pick.readonly = .f.
frm.grid_list.column1.pick.tabstop  = .t.
frm.grid_list.column1.sparse = .f.


endif
endfor

endpro

enddefine
```

Thanks anyone could help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few adjustments for you...  Your for loop, should be a FOR EACH, otherwise, I had a compile error.

```
For EACH frm in _screen.Forms
```

Another shortcut for you on opening the table as editable is the READWRITE clause... and you can ensure the cursor is closed before querying with shortcut syntax

*/ Since SELECT( "someAlias" ) will return either the work area it is opened in
*/ or zero if the alias is not used, the USE IN states to CLOSE the table/alias
*/ in the given work area.

```
use in select( "tmpcur" )  && pre-close your read-only cursor result
use in select( "tmpcur_" )  && pre-close your read-write version of cursor
```

*/ Now, the query... FIRST, change the "PICK" column to a LOGICAL as that is
*/ the basis of binding to a checkbox control, not a space character...
*/ Then change the INTO clause...

```
select ;
      .f. as pick,;
      AllOtherFields ;
   from ;
      purc ;
   where ;
      alltrim(inv_no) = alltrim(this.txt_search.value) ;
   into ;
      cursor tmpcur
```

*/ Now, just open the result again as it was pre-closed 
*/ if already open before the query

```
  USE DBF("tmpcur") in 0 AGAIN alias tmpcur_
```

Now, all you are missing is the binding of your checkbox control.  Change your

```
frm.grid_list.column1.bound = .T.
```

By setting to TRUE, you are stating you want it bound to each individual record.

Comment: There is so much thanks to your helps and I'm able to fix it.

Comment: For last mentioned things, I'm unable to put readwrite clause at behind of my cursor since I'm using Visual foxpro 6.0 which so far do not support it.

Comment: @koklimabc, revised code for VFP 6 implementation... still simplifies code for you.  Also, click on the link at the top for Help --> Tour for site etiquette.  Don't put an answer based on an answer provided, but checkmark the answer that helped you solve your question... A comment to the answer such as ... the Bound = .T. fixed it... thanks. vs an entirely new answer posted back.

Answer (score 0):

There is so much thanks to your helps and I'm able to fix it. The check is finally bound to individual row.

There is only 2 modification done in my final code :

```
If NOT USED('tmpcur_')
            USE DBF("tmpcur") in 0 AGAIN alias tmpcur_
else
            USE IN select('tmpcur_') /*Change*/
            USE DBF("tmpcur") in 0 AGAIN alias tmpcur_
endif

frm.grid_list.column1.bound                 = .t. /*It is bound to .f. in before */
```

For last mentioned things, I'm unable to put readwrite clause at behind of my cursor since I'm using Visual foxpro 6.0 which so far do not support it.